# Cloud Firestore: check if value exists without knowing field name

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I would like to check if a certain value is present in my Cloud Firestore collection through all the present fields and have back the document ID that has at least one field whose value is the one searched.

In this example, the code should give back only 2 records when I look for `"Peter"`: `8cyMJG7uNgVoenA63brG` and `fnk0kgW7gSBc3EdOYWxD`.

I know how to do a search when the field name is known. But in this case, I cannot know the field name at prior.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In your example, "Peter" is in the `Address` property and in the second in `Name`. In how many others can be? Do you need an exact match or `Peter Pan` should also be a match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know the name of a field, you can't perform any queries against its value.  Firestore requires queries to use some index, and indexes always work with the names of fields in your documents.

Comment: I know the name of the collection. But I have to look through all the fields of that collection.

Comment: I understand that.  You can't do that with a Firestore query.  Probably you need a full text search engine instead.